# Ability to automatically redirect a URL

Tags: plugins, php, css, urls

I have a website allows people to create fundraising campaigns for selling t-shirts.

They have the ability to log-on, create product and then create a campaign with a deadline, etc. The plugin that makes this possible creates a url for their campaign, but it is long:

`www.mylongdomainname.com/projects/NAMEOFCAMPAIGN`

Obviously, I could manually create a redirect and then provide that to the client after they have created it, but I want to have something that does it automatically!

So if I owned another domain that was exclusively for the purpose of redirects, we will call it `www.shortdomain.us`

Is there a way (plugin, etc.) that `www.shortdomain.us/NAMEOFCAMPAIGN` could be automatically created once `www.mylongdomainname.com/projects/NAMEOFCAMPAIGN` was created?

Comment: To further clarify the final paragraph, I want the shortdomain to be created and then redirect to the longdomain.

Comment: If you can show your research and coding efforts so far then you'll have more chance of help. [ask] Plugin recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Andy-  I don't even know what to call what I'm trying to do so therefore it is hard to search for the solution.  That is why I have resorted to a forum like this in hopes that someone understands what I am asking/trying to do and can direct me to where I need to go.

Comment: Searching for "URL shortener api" seems fruitful

Answer (score 0):

It's not a WordPress problem, but....

You can use something like [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) or you just set up the short domain on hosting and either redirect using mod_rewrite or using PHP's `header()` function.

Comment: Setting up a bit.ly is a manual process.  I want an automatic solution (if there is one)   Thanks.

Comment: Please read the rest of my answer.

Comment: Sorry.  I will look into this.

Comment: Sdexp-  YOU DA MAN!!!!

Comment: Bitly even has a WP plugin!